# adding array using model to mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb, model

I have added a user to my mongodb collection called users using this model:

```
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Password:")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Confirm:")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Email:")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Username:")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Firtname:")]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Lastname:")]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Country:")]
    public string Country { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "City:")]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Birthdate:")]
    public int Birthdate { get; set; }
    public List<Team> Teams { get; set; }
```

as you can se it also have a list of teams in it. So now im using this code to get the user:

```
         var query_id = Query.EQ("_id", ObjectId.Parse(Session["ID"].ToString()));
        User entity = Context.Users.FindOne(query_id);
```

And now i want to add a list to the mongodb object with the data from my team model:

```
  public int TeamID { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int LeagueID { get; set; }

    public Points Points = new Points();

    public List<Player> Player { get; set; }
```

How do i add the team-modeldata to my userobject in the mongodb collection?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using LINQ / AutoMapping features of MongoDB.

```
var databaseClient = new MongoClient(DatabaseConnectionString);
var server = databaseClient.GetServer();
var database = server.GetDatabase("Users");
var collection = database.GetCollection<User>("users");

var user = collection.AsQueryable().First(o => o._id == YOURSESSIONID);

user.Teams.Add(new Team { TeamID = 0, TeamName = "Some Team" });
```